# Is it possible tpo use the excel weeksum function in SharePoint to return the week number from a date column?

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, number

I am new to SharePoint and I know that in Excel you can use the WEEKSUM function to return the week number from a date column. Is it possible to do the same in SharePoint 2013? If so how can this be done please?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new calculated column (GO TO: List settings>Create Column>Calculated Column).  Then use something like the formula in [this article](http://www.allthingssharepoint.nl/calculateweeknumber/).  Watch out for fiddly brackets, sometimes you'll find you need one more than you think.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint only has a very basic set of Functions that work in Formulas.
WEEKNUM is not one of them.

For a complete list see: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

The WEEKDAY function shows an example for an American Week Number is: